# Error After Dependency Injection in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui

Having a few troubles setting up the dependancy injection in Maui. Pretty sure I've done it right but I get a strange error when trying to run the Android Project.

I get this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Android Activity can't be null.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:line 379
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlNode.cs:line 92
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlNode.cs:line 153
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlNode.cs:line 210
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:line 210
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:line 78
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:line 53
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:line 49
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[LoginPage](LoginPage view, Type callingType) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:line 37
```

It occurs in one of the generated code files:

```
[assembly: global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlResourceId("BoB.Mobile.Pages.LoginPage.xaml", "Pages/LoginPage.xaml", typeof(global::BoB.Mobile.Pages.LoginPage))]
namespace BoB.Mobile.Pages
{
    [global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlFilePath("Pages/LoginPage.xaml")]
    public partial class LoginPage : global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ContentPage
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen", "1.0.0.0")]
#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER
#endif
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I think I have this set up correctly :

MauiProgram.cs

```
 public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("Montserrat-Black.ttf", "Montserrat-Black");
            });
        
        builder.Services.AddBusinessDependencies();
        builder.Services.AddSDKDependencies();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginPageModel>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<HttpClient>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICoreMethods, CoreMethods>();
        
        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
        using var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BoB.Mobile.appsettings.development.json");
#else
        using var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BoB.Mobile.appsettings.production.json");
#endif
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(stream)
            .Build();

        var sdkSettings = config.GetSection("settings").Get<SdkSettings>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(sdkSettings);

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(LoginPage page)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = page;
    }
}
```

LoginPageModel.cs

```
public class LoginPageModel : BasePageModel
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    private readonly ICoreMethods _coreMethods;
    
    public LoginPageModel(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, ICoreMethods coreMethods)
    {
        _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        _coreMethods = coreMethods;

        OnLoginPressedCommand = new Command(OnLoginPressed);
    }
}
```

and lastly the LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage(LoginPageModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I would expect a different error message, but first make sure you have added `builder.Services.AddTransient/Singleton/Scoped<IAuthenticationManager..`, etc. DI must be told how to resolve ALL parameter types for View/VM constructors. All the way down: If the classes' that implement those interfaces have constructor parameters, you'll need those types too.

Comment: I have a similar problem, when adding my MainPage as constructor parameter to the App, this results in a XamlParseException. All dependencies are registered correctly, but the MAUI DI does not seem to resolve them correctly. I'm currently targeting windows.